# Exchange Web Service error : "Resources are unavailable. Try again later., Cannot seek a row."

Tags: exchange-server, exchangewebservices

When I'm trying to get email items from Exchange (Office 365) using EWS.
I'm trying to do that by chunks with 500 messages. Sometimes, when I'm call method findItem I'm getting error : "Resources are unavailable. Try again later., Cannot seek a row."

Googling didn't provide anythings. I don't understand what does it mean and how to solve this.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I can't say as I've run into this specific error before, but when dealing with O365, you'll often encounter these kinds of "go away, come back later" messages, and will have to implement a retry mechanism.  Reducing your chunk size might help as well, but the message does contain your next step, i.e. "Try again later."  Now if the request never succeeds after retry, this might be a deeper issue, but it does sound like a transient error from what you've described.

Comment: Exponential back-off retry is implemented, but in many cases it doesn't help. Even, reducing chunk size, it just happens, usually on large folders, where findItem operation requires lot of resources.

Answer (score 0):

The email being retrieved is within a folder that may have too many items. Retrieving such items usually returns similar errors. Splitting the folder such that each folder holds a max of 70,000 items may help.

Comment: Well, it's a customer folder, so in this case it can't help. Thanks